# What's the remaining part of Judy's line before she asks Ava a question?

Tags: plot-explanation, ava

In Ava (2020), Ava and Judy are talking about Michael's gambling habit:

> Ava: You're sure he's playing cards?
>
> Judy: It's okay. I f*cking... I hate it. 'Cause part of me is hoping
> you know where he is, and **the other part is gonna be pissed if...**
> So do you?
>
> Ava: No. Sorry.

What's the remaining part of Judy's line before she asks Ava a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is "... you know where he is"

Judy is expressing that she both hopes and will be annoyed if Ava knows where Michael is.